# How to find the progress timings of a video in an iphone using MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios5, uibutton, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a requirement where i have a video playing on my screen and i have two buttons good and  bad. I need to find the progress timings of the video playing and capture the button clicks good and bad at the appropriate timings the button is clicked. I tried looking on how to find the progress timings of a video when it is playing. But Alas!!!!. I need to capture the button clicks when the video is playing and compare the clicks if good or bad is clicked. Any suggestion or help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `currentPlaybackTime` property of the `MPMediaPlayback` protocol.
`MPMoviePlayerController` adheres to that protocol, hence you can use it directly on any instance of that class.

e.g.

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [...];
[...]
NSLog(@"current time: %g", player.currentPlaybackTime);
```

---

From the [MPMediaPlayback Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html);

```
currentPlaybackTime
```

The current position of the playhead. (required)

```
@property(nonatomic) NSTimeInterval currentPlaybackTime
```

***Discussion***

> For video-on-demand or progressively downloaded content, this value is
>   measured in seconds from the beginning of the current item. Changing
>   the value of this property moves the playhead to the new location. For
>   content streamed live from a server, this value represents the time
>   from the beginning of the playlist when it was first loaded.

Availability
Available in iOS 3.2 and later.
Declared In
MPMediaPlayback.h

Comment: I have tried out the above mentioned solution. It was perfect. But i have a doubt regarding the MPMediaPlayBack Protocol. The protocol defines 7 methods. - (void)prepareToPlay{}
- (void)play{}
- (void)stop{}
- (void)pause{}
- (void)beginSeekingForward{}
- (void)beginSeekingBackward{}
- (void)endSeeking{} . We should definitely implement all these methods even if it not necessary. I doubt if this cause any potential risk to the mediaplayer object. Can u please confirm if this is ok? I have implemented all the methods shown above.

Comment: You do not implement those methods at all, the MPMoviePlayerController already does that.

Comment: If i dont implement those methods, i am getting warnings"Incomplete Implementation" I am using the MPMoviePlayerController as a subview to my ViewController.

Comment: That is because you declared your UIViewController to adhere to the mentioned protocol which is wrong and pointless.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I was under a feeling that i need to implement the MPMediaPlayback Protocol to use the currentPlaybackTime property. Yes, its not needed. I have checked the same. Thanks for the help @Till